# How can i have access to stored files on my different server via php header?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, header

Is there any way to download stored file in sub domain(dl1.example.com) via dl.php file that's stored in original domain name(example.com/dl.php?id=12)

In this case that file that need's to be downloadable is located on dl1(sub domain from different server and connected via add DNS record option on cpanel)

dl.php working with php header to make links for clients

Url fetched from db ($path) and used as an input in below function:

```
downloadFile($path,$file_name, 1024, false);
```

$path variable is contain something like below variable:

```
$path="http://dl1.example.com/Lamp%20with%20phpmyadmin.mp4";
```

I don't have any problem with stored files on my master domain name, my problems occurred when i want to use sub domain to make downloadable links

All of my codes:

```
/* List of File Types */
function fileTypes($extension){
$fileTypes['swf'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
$fileTypes['pdf'] = 'application/pdf';
$fileTypes['exe'] = 'application/octet-stream';
$fileTypes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
$fileTypes['doc'] = 'application/msword';
$fileTypes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
$fileTypes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
$fileTypes['gif'] = 'image/gif';
$fileTypes['png'] = 'image/png';
$fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image/jpg';
$fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image/jpg';
$fileTypes['rar'] = 'application/rar';

$fileTypes['ra'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
$fileTypes['ram'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
$fileTypes['ogg'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';

$fileTypes['wav'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
$fileTypes['wmv'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
$fileTypes['avi'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
$fileTypes['asf'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
$fileTypes['divx'] = 'video/x-msvideo';

$fileTypes['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg';
$fileTypes['mp4'] = 'audio/mpeg';
$fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video/mpeg';
$fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video/mpeg';
$fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video/mpeg';
$fileTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime';
$fileTypes['swf'] = 'video/quicktime';
$fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video/quicktime';
$fileTypes['m4a'] = 'video/quicktime';
$fileTypes['aac'] = 'video/quicktime';
$fileTypes['m3u'] = 'video/quicktime';
return $fileTypes[$extention];
};

/*
Parameters: downloadFile(File Location, File Name,
max speed, is streaming
If streaming - videos will show as videos, images as images
instead of download prompt
*/
function downloadFile($fileLocation, $fileName, $maxSpeed = 100,     $doStream = false) {
if (connection_status() != 0)
    return(false);
//    in some old versions this can be pereferable to get extention
//    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $fileName)));
$extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$contentType = fileTypes($extension);
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header('Content-Type: $contentType');

$contentDisposition = 'attachment';

if ($doStream == true) {
    /* extensions to stream */
    $array_listen = array('mp3', 'm3u', 'm4a', 'mid', 'ogg', 'ra', 'ram', 'wm',
        'wav', 'wma', 'aac', '3gp', 'avi', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpg', 'swf', 'wmv', 'divx', 'asf');
    if (in_array($extension, $array_listen)) {
        $contentDisposition = 'inline';
    }
}

if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) {
    $fileName = preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileName, substr_count($fileName, '.') - 1);
    header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition;
        filename=\"$fileName\"");
} else {
    header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition;
        filename=\"$fileName\"");
}

header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
$range = 0;
$size = filesize($fileLocation);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=", $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
    str_replace($range, "-", $range);
    $size2 = $size - 1;
    $new_length = $size - $range;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range$size2/$size");
} else {
    $size2 = $size - 1;
    header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size");
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);
}

if ($size == 0) {
    die('Zero byte file! Aborting download');
}
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
$fp = fopen("$fileLocation", "rb");

fseek($fp, $range);

while (!feof($fp) and ( connection_status() == 0)) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    print(fread($fp, 1024 * $maxSpeed));
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
fclose($fp);

return((connection_status() == 0) and ! connection_aborted());
}

/* Implementation */
// downloadFile('path_to_file/1.mp3', '1.mp3', 1024, false);


if(isset($_GET['i']) && is_numeric($_GET['i'])){
$file_id=input_security($_GET['i']);
$linkque=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM download_links WHERE dl_id='".$file_id."'");
$checkexist=mysqli_num_rows($linkque);
$f_row=mysqli_fetch_array($linkque);
    if($checkexist==0){
        echo 'Invalid file id';
    }else if($checkexist>=1 && $f_row['payment_model']=="free"){
    /* Function: download with resume/speed/stream options */
        $path=$f_row['url'];
        $sep_parts = pathinfo($path);
        $file_name  = $sep_parts['basename'];
        $file_ext   = $sep_parts['extension'];
        if (file_exists($path)) {   
        downloadFile($path,$file_name, 1024, false);
        }else{
            echo "File is not exist or url is wrong.";
        }
}else if($checkexist>=1 && $f_row['payment_model']=="nofree"){
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    $client_id=input_security($_SESSION['username']);
    $client_id_query="SELECT userid FROM users WHERE emailuser='".$client_id."'";
    $session_query=mysqli_query($connection,$client_id_query);
    $clientidrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($session_query);
    $client_id=$clientidrow['user_id'];
    $link_pid=$f_row['post_id'];
        $userorderque=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM user_orders WHERE post_id='".$link_pid."' AND order_client_id='".$client_id."'");
        $checkorderexist=mysqli_num_rows($userorderque);
        $checktobuy_row=mysqli_fetch_array($userorderque);


        if($checkorderexist>=1 && $checktobuy_row['paid']==1){

        $path=$f_row['url'];
        $sep_parts = pathinfo($path);
        $file_name  = $sep_parts['basename'];
        $file_ext   = $sep_parts['extension'];
        if (file_exists($path)){
        //echo "thank you for purchase and support us. You can download now.";
            downloadFile($path,$file_name, 1024, false);
        }else{
            echo "File is not exist or url is wrong.";
        }
        }else if($checkorderexist>=1 && $checktobuy_row['paid']==0){
            echo "You Need to pay for download this file";
        }
    }else{
        echo "This file needs to login";
    }



}else{
    echo "You don't have permission to download this file please purchase this product and trying to download again";
    }
}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

How can i have access to stored files on my different server that's connected to my domain name as sub domain (dl1.example.com) from my script that's stored on my domain name (i mean my master web server host (example.com)) ?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: it s not clear what you trying to do.

Comment: I want to share product links, but just for customers who pay.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear how your communication flow is, but from your description you just deal with a cross domain problem. You might be able to go on by allowing cross domain calls on your servers by adding this header to your servers response for download:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Good examples using different environments can be found here:

https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); Not worked, can you show me one simple example please?

Comment: i guess we could chat for a while now about this. Your case description does not even make clear if Cross domain really is your probelm. If it is, you need to look up on your own about certain solutions for your special environment, or update your question providing more details accordingly